# Rails: Find all occurrences of internal 404 links (is Rails "leaking" URLs?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, http-status-code-404

I came across something curious and was wondering how to fix it within Rails.

In my app, I have a `Country` model; it already contains records for all countries I'll ever need. However, many of them don't contain any data or are otherwise not yet relevant. These countries yield a 404 error, as they would if the record didn't exist in the first place:

```
begin
    @country = Country.friendly.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @country = nil
end

if !@country.nil? && Country.with_data.include?(@country)
    # render the view
else
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :status => :not_found
end
```

So assuming that e.g. France contains data while Andorra doesn't, the following should happen:

- mysite/country/france --> HTTP 200 OK
- mysite/country/andorra --> HTTP 404 Not found
- mysite/country/randomstring123 --> HTTP 404 Not found

This all works fine. However, what's curious is that when I track my site in Google Webmaster Tools, it is actually aware of some of the URLs that point to "empty" countries, and shows them to me as 404-yielding "crawling errors". (E.g., it knows `mysite/country/andorra`.) What I can't see is where Google got those URLs from. Those links are also not included in the WT "Internal Links" section, so that doesn't help.

The `routes.rb` excludes the index action:
`resources :countries, path: "country", except: :index`

I generate a sitemap with a custom controller, but it excludes the countries in question.

I conclude that there are two likely options:

1. It is possible that an earlier version of the sitemap controller included "empty" countries. They might then still be tried by Google eventually (as are some old URLs from a much outdated site structure > 9 months ago).
2. Otherwise, Rails somehow would have to "leak" URLs to these empty countries. Is there any "internal" way to check that? I'll also run external 404 checks but it would be good to know if I can somehow get an efficient output much alike rake routes somehow.

Comment: check for `robots.txt` in your public folder.

Comment: It does not explicitly allow or disallow any URLs related to the model in question.

Comment: so you mean to say, all lines are commented as it comes by default?

Comment: Then if you want to disallow such urls you can do so with `Disallow` option with regex which matches ur url pattern.

Comment: But that is neither the point of my approach, nor solves my initial question. I want those URLs to return 404 (which they do), not specifically disallow stuff that should yield 404s.

Comment: Firstly, you are rendering a file and not redirecting to a path/url so ur address bar has the wrong url. Since these urls are not disallowed, they are being scraped by google and other bots. So, i don't think it is a leak. Creating a route of `not_found` and redirecting to it might is what you are looking for.

Comment: 1. What is the point of disallowing every possible URL? URLs that would point to non-existing records are treated the same way as URLs that point to empty records. (I've added more code to the original post to reflect that.) 2. Redirecting away from URLs that should yield 404 is not a smart idea. So the address bar shows exactly the URL it's supposed to show. (See e.g. https://moz.com/blog/are-404-pages-always-bad-for-seo) 3. Google doesn't just randomly scrape URLs. Google has these URLs from somewhere; the way I understand your answer is that so far nothing points *against* a leak, also.